# Writable External Objects between 2 salesforce Org

Tags: apex, integration, salesforce2salesforce, auth

I am working on a requirement in which I need to write on some external object between 2 salesforce org.

I have tried to use the s2s connect but they are not working as Writable external objects aren’t supported with the Salesforce adapter for Lightning Connect.

Is there any other way or process to do this

Comment: what exact requirement do you have? do you need to transfer records from one salesforce instance to another or do you need to transfer records from salesforce instance to external system?

Comment: Transferring the records as well from one salesforce to another. I have already tried to use auth provider with named credentials , but its not working. :(

Comment: to transfer the records between two Salesforce organization on the same login domain, there is standard feature "Salesforce to Salesforce". Have you tried to activate it and use it?

Comment: Hi @Patlatus , Thanks . But I have to use the lightning connect for that. I already know about the stos functionality and the partnerconnectionobject in it.

Comment: do you face any problems with lightning connect? have you read this article https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connector_external_objects_writeable.htm ?

Comment: I have already read this article But before that I need to have a connection between 2 salesforce org. As well as I do not need to use salesforce adapter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51235/discussion-between-cloud-lover-and-patlatus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working as the salesforce URL is not exposed as odata. We can use the updated feature in spring 17 through which we can connect two org and make the object writable

Comment: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000lg6kQAA